# Hello, I'm trying to build Apk for my project and I got these errors, I tried every solution on the internet but still not working.. any idea?

Tags: flutter, dart, build, apk, project

Execution failed for task ':clipboard_manager:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\zraed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\31ffd94dd4be5a0ccaa73c0d1aa53e0e\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

```
 C:\Users\zraed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\31ffd94dd4be5a0ccaa73c0d1aa53e0e\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'clipboard_manager'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Are you building `release` apk for your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `sdk.dir` with following command:

```
   flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```

Or you can create a local.properties file under the Android folder of your project. And add the following line:

```
     sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

There is a blog about this issue in [here](https://medium.com/@selvakumar_P/sdk-location-not-found-f7bdf13dc09).